# Goldbach's conjecture if 1 is counted as prime

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I was grading some homework from a Survey of Mathematics course. They were asked to verify that Goldbach's conjecture holds for the first 15 even numbers greater than or equal to 4. A couple of students wrote "solutions" such as 12 = 11 + 1. It struck me in passing as an *interesting* error. What if the definition of primes was modified so that 1 would count as a prime? Then Goldbach's conjecture could be stated simply as every even natural number is the sum of two primes (since of course 2 = 1 + 1). More formally (and without modifying the definition of a prime): Every even number greater than 4 is either the sum of two primes or is the successor of a prime. Surely this weakening of Goldbach's conjecture has been studied, but I wasn't able to find any discussion of it.

Has this variation of Goldbach's conjecture been studied? If so, what is known about it?

Comment: According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldbachConjecture.html, Goldbach himself considered $1$ a prime, so there is at least that.

Comment: @Sil That is a nice tidbit. My main motivation for asking the question is that when I pass back the homework I want to mention this mistake but to give it a positive spin. If nothing else, I'll mention that Goldbach himself would have accepted their solution. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DIQofiPqhJ_s&ved=2ahUKEwjh1ai5udHkAhUXoZ4KHcFwCN0QwqsBMAB6BAgGEAQ&usg=AOvVaw3nwab6nw4-5Mr8b2DDiT3- historically it was but they kept having to exclude it to have nice properties. So they redefined the term.

Comment: I never was aware of this slight weakened version, I didn't know that Goldbach allowed $1$ as a prime. Anyway, I would have been surprised if this version would have been solved. As far as I know, Goldbach was not proven for any nontrivial subset of the even numbers, for example, the powers of two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Origins @Peter

Comment: $p+q=2n\land p=2k+1\land q=2j+1\implies n-1=j+k$ where if 1 is involved has one of $k,j$ is 0. That's about my best so far. Oh, and neither k,j are of form $2ab+a+b$ via the sieve of sundaram.